# How to prevent not in results from appending to union clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, union, notin

I am trying to union two result sets and omit the results from the first set when returning the second unioned set.

However, when the second set is selected it is appending the data from the sub-query.

```
declare @bool nvarchar(1) = 'Y'

select [name[
from table_1
where @bool = 'N'

union

select [name]
from table_2 t2
where @bool = 'Y'
and [name] not in (
  select [name]
  from table_1
)
```

How can I select the second part when `@bool = 'Y'` without the `not in` sub-query appending its results to the dataset?

Comment: As you have written the query, the results should come from one of the subqueries, but not both.

Comment: you query is already doing what you want

Comment: @RyanWilson It's a switch to simplify the API when pulling in data from disparate sources.

Comment: @eshirvana I see that now. I had a longer chained query that was missing part of a where-clause statement.